# Nginx - web server AND reverse proxy, on same server, how to

Tags: nginx

I currently have nginx working perfectly as reverse proxy to server unifi's wifi controller, via subdomain and connection automatically bumped from http to https. I now need to serve a basic php page from the same server on the same subdomain with the file sunder/var/ww/html/pages/ and a bit stuck as to how to achieve this, ive tried adding location blocks and server blocks, but go around in circles with varying errors :)

Following is my .conf for the site, any help appreciated

```
#/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

server_tokens off;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

server {
listen 80;
server_name _;
return 301 https://wifi.domain.com.au$request_uri;
error_log /var/log/unifi/nginx.log;

location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
default_type "text/plain";
root /var/www/html/letsencrypt;
}
}

server {
listen 443 ssl default_server http2;
server_name wifi.domain.com.au;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wifi.domain.com.au/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wifi.domain.com.au/privkey.pem;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
keepalive_timeout 300;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_ciphers  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
error_log /var/log/unifi/nginx.log;
client_max_body_size 8M;
proxy_cache off;
proxy_store off;

location / {
include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443$request_uri;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
}
```

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble, and just use a different subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i got it working thusly...

```
#/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
server_tokens off;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

server {
listen 80;
server_name _;
return 301 https://wifi.domain.com.au$request_uri;
error_log /var/log/unifi/nginx.log;

location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
default_type "text/plain";
root /var/www/html/letsencrypt;
}
}

server {
listen 443 ssl default_server http2;
server_name wifi.domain.com.au;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wifi.domain.com.au/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wifi.domain.com.au/privkey.pem;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
keepalive_timeout 300;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_ciphers  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
error_log /var/log/unifi/nginx.log;
client_max_body_size 8M;
proxy_cache off;
proxy_store off;

location / {
include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443$request_uri;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location /admin {
include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81$request_uri;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
}
```

I did try and keep it all in nginx, but had horrific time trying to get php scripts working via it, spent far too many hours googling nginx php blocks and trying the myriad of supposed fixes...gave up...lighttpd to the rescue

Installed lighthttpd, and set its port to 81 and php working out of the box

Now i can access my unifi controller on the main subdomain URL, i.e.e https://sub.domain.com, and the new php pages at https://sub.domain.com/admin all goodness